# Update model and table in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angularjs though its been around for a while. I decided to convert some of my C++ .NET code to angularjs and I'm running into some trouble with updating a table dynamically so to say.
This is my html page

```
<div ng-controller="missionsController" ng-init="loadList()" class="inner">
<section>
    <div>
        <header class="major">
            <h1>
                <span>{{PageTitle}}</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>S/N</td>
                <td>Region</td>
                <td>District Count</td>
                <td>Zone Count</td>
                <td>Branch Count</td>
                <td>Sub Branch Count</td>
                <td>Adult Attendance</td>
                <td>Children Attendance</td>
                <td>Total Attendance</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in adminLevelList">
                <td><span ng-if="$index != adminLevelList.length - 1">{{$index + 1}}.</span></td>
                <td>{{x.RegionName}}</td>
                <td>{{x.nDistricts}}</td>
                <td>{{x.nZones}}</td>
                <td>{{x.nBranches}}</td>
                <td>{{x.nSubbranches}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Attendance.AdultCount}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Attendance.AdultCount}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Attendance.AdultCount}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

Its a simple table that displays data with ng-repeat

Here is my js code

```
    'use strict';

angular.module("afmweca")
    .controller("missionsController", function ($scope, $stateParams, api) {

        $scope.loadList = function () {
            if ($stateParams.AL) {
                $scope.AL = $stateParams.AL;
                var AL = $scope.AL;
                api.getAllAdminLevelReport(AL)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        $scope.adminLevelList = result;
                        }
                    }, function (reason) {
                        $log.log("Operation Failed: " + reason);
                    });

                if (AL == 2) {
                    $scope.PageTitle = "Region List";
                }
                else if (AL == 3) {
                    $scope.PageTitle = "District List";
                }
                else if (AL == 4) {
                    $scope.PageTitle = "Zone List";
                }
                else if (AL == 5) {
                    $scope.PageTitle = "Branch List";
                }
                else if (AL == 6) {
                    $scope.PageTitle = "Sub Branch List";
                }
             }
        }

    });
```

The page simply load data from a HTTP service called API, which does a HTTP get call to another server for data to be loaded. Depending on the value of AL, the data returned is different.
However, after the first load of the page, the table doesn't update with the new data when the value of AL is changed. I'm using routes to change the value of AL. The HTTP call returns the new data but the new data is not loaded in **adminLevelList** neither does the table update. 
I tried all sort of suggestions online - including apply, applySync, and so on - doesn't seem to work for me. Am I wrong in wanting to use the same page to display different sets of data depending on the value supplied?
How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Are you sure that http call for data is made when you changed AL value through routes ? Based on your code, I see that data is loaded and updated on scope only in `loadList()` which you happen to call in ng-init.

Comment: 100% sure. I added log in the api service to be sure the service is being called. The data in Network view on the Chrome Console also show the correct data is being returned back.

Comment: In dev tools, put a debug point in success callback of then() and see control is coming to the line where you're updating adminLevelList with the result from server. Usually it's `result.data` that has the actual data unless you modified it in getAllAdminLevelReport()

Comment: Never mind result.data, if it worked in ng-init once it should work properly this time. I see an additional curly brace in then() first argument after `$scope.adminLevelList = result;`, hope it's  a copy-paste error.

Comment: Yea. Must be. I was trying to remove unnecessary things from the code. It does get it the first time. Its updating the model the next time that doesn't work. Could it be because its an http call?

Comment: Can you add the piece showing how you're updating AL through routes ? Route definitions might also help

Comment: I just debugged your code and found the root cause. Posted my answer below. Feel free to upvote and accept if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in your `apiService.js`. You're using a **global/shared** promise (`defered`) object to resolve and reject data from **all the http service** calls.

Each service should have it's own promise object so that they can resolve the data as and when the response is available.

```
this.getAllAdminLevelReport = function (AL) {
      $log.log('API CALL (getAllAdminLevelReport(' + AL + ')...');

      /* use a local promise so that you get a new instance 
         for every method invocation*/

      var defered = $q.defer();

      // removing rest of the code for the sake of brevity. No change here

      return defered.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arkantos. Using a local promise object worked perfectly.